# Data wrangling to map timing and frequency of the notes in a recording

Tags: r, time-series, data-wrangling, data-transform, acoustics

I have a dataset having 216 sound recording files represented by the start and end timing (in seconds) and the respective frequencies of the notes sung by male and female birds:

| note | sound.files | start | end | freq | sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2.7 | 3.2 | 1.55 | f |
| 2 | a | 3.2 | 3.6 | 1.17 | m |
| 3 | a | 3.6 | 4.0 | 1.17 | f |
| 4 | a | 3.9 | 4.3 | 0.89 | m |
| 5 | a | 4.3 | 4.4 | 0.79 | f |
| 1 | b | 1.9 | 2.3 | 1.45 | f |
| 2 | b | 2.4 | 2.7 | 3.71 | m |
| 3 | b | 2.6 | 3.1 | 1.36 | f |
| 4 | b | 3.1 | 3.4 | 3.62 | m |
| 5 | b | 3.9 | 4.4 | 0.79 | m |
| 6 | b | 4.5 | 4.6 | 1.17 | f |

I require to transform the data in a long format with time-mapped frequency values of male and female birds for each recording, e.g.:

| sound.files | time | m | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2.7 | 0 | 1.55 |
| a | 2.8 | 0 | 1.55 |
| a | 2.9 | 0 | 1.55 |
| a | 3.0 | 0 | 1.55 |
| a | 3.1 | 0 | 1.55 |
| a | 3.2 | 1.17 | 0 |
| a | 3.3 | 1.17 | 0 |

I tried the following code but it did not work and running into an error:

*Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x object 'freq' not found:*

code:

```
cum_call1 <- function(start,end,freq){
  data.frame(time = seq(start,end,by = .1), calling = 1, freq= mean(freq))
}

cum_expand1 <- function(start,end){
  data.frame(time = seq(start,end,by = .1))
}

data.frame$start <- round(data.frame$start,1)
data.frame$end <- round(data.frame$end,1)


duet_call <- data.frame %>% 
  group_by(sound.files,sex,note) %>% 
  summarise(cum_call1(start,end,freq)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-note)
```

Is there any right/better way to go about it? Any suggestions are welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not base R but the pivot_wider function from one of the tidyverse packages should help. You're  pivoting the column to be wider not longer as one column (sex) is becoming two.(m,f)

```
library(tidyverse)

pivot_wider(data,names_from=sex,values_from=freq)
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan, can you please elaborate more? I have a two-step code, where the first step I mentioned in the sample and it was to time-map the data, the second step was to use the transformed file for pivot longer. e.g., `duet_wide <- duet_call %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = sex,values_from= freq,id_cols = c(sound.files,time)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c('f','m'))
` . But I am getting errors in the very first step!

Comment: Have you checked that the cum_call function works on its own? The error is happening when summarise calls the returned table from cum_call.